# PSD to HTML, Mailjet

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеется задача перевести psd в HTML, но есть уточнение, что CSS не нужен. После сказано что делать это надо в Mailjet. Собственно вопрос: как же я без CSS это сделаю? мне просто необходимо стили вписывать в HTML файле? правильно я понял? или вовсе без них обойтись? Кто знающий, подскажите!

Comment: ну так почитайте сначала о верстке писем, Вас видимо просят сверстать именно письмо (рассылку), а не простой макет.

Comment: Это ясно,  просто как я онлайн добавлю например файлы в html?

Comment: не понятно о каких файлах идет речь, письмо это один html файл с инлайновыми стилями. А заливать это уже особенности ресурса. Думаю есть туториалы по тому как залить туда файлы или код.

Comment: Теперь вроде бы понял. ПРосто наотрез сказали "без CSS", я и сижу в недоумении...спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <center style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%;">
       <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0"><tr><td>
<![endif]-->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><td align="center">
               <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300"     align="center"><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Блок номер 1 -->
         <span style="display:inline-block; width:300px;">
             Контент блока
         </span>
        <!-- Блок номер 1 -->
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
 </td></tr></table>
 </td>
 <td align="center">
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr><td>
 <![endif]-->
        <!-- Блок номер 2 -->
         <span style="display:inline-block; width:300px;">
              Контент блока
         </span>
        <!-- Блок номер 2 -->
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </td></tr></table>
        </td>
        </tr></table>
        <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
     </center>   
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Подбробное описание верстки писем](https://habrahabr.ru/post/252279/)